# Як перекласти з англійської "in terms of number of letters"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, відповідник

Фраза виникла в контексті обговорення як англійці вітають одне одного:

> *In terms of number of letters* "How are you?" and "How is it?" are identical.

*З точки зору кількості літер* фрази ідентичні/рівнозначні? *В плані кількості літер*...?

Можливо це дійсно коректні варіанти, але я не певен. Питаю, щоб упевнитись.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання про переклад містило: (1) пояснення **своїми словами** іншомовного слова; (2) **контекст**, в якому автор збирається використовувати перекладене слово; (3) продемонструвати власну спробу знайти відповідь і (4) пояснити, чим са́ме знайдені варіанти не підходять. Запитання, які не відповідають цим умовам, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді.

Comment: Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Comment: Погоджуюся з паном bytebuster'ом, треба змінити запитання.
Від себе додам: "зважаючи на кількість літер".

Comment: @P.Vowk Я думав що я змінив запитання таким чином, що тепер воно відповідає усім чотирьом пунктам. Щось ще залишилось?

Comment: Щодо четвертого, наприклад, я не впевнений.

Comment: @P.Vowk Я не був впевнений, чи мої варіанти підходять. Тому запитав. В мене немає якихось конкретних причин чому вони не підходять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можна:

- «З погляду кількості літер…».

  Зокрема «Словник української мови» в 11 томах в статті [«погляд»](http://sum.in.ua/s/poghljad) пише:

  > ♦ З погляду: <…> б) (чого, якого) стос. до чого, з боку чого. Пролог мені дуже сподобався в першім уступі.., навіть нічого не можу сказати з погляду стилю (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 437).
- На практиці використовують «з точки зору кількості літер…». Хоча думки щодо того, [чи справді українській мові приматанна конструкція «точка зору»](/q/3990) — дехто вважає, що загалом її слід замінити на конструкцію «кут зору», а в цьому випадку «кут зору» радше недоречне — однак принаймні «Словник української мови» в 11 томах словосполучення «точка зору» фіксує і на практиці це словосполучення вживається в потрібному значенні, наприклад:

  > В дальшому до роботи треба ставитися з точки зору бойового виховання частин. //«Вісті ВУЦВК», 1927.
- Де-факто вживається в цьому значенні і «в плані кількості літер…». Хоча я не бачу жодного тлумачення слова «план» у тлумачних словниках, яке б дозволяло таке переносне значення, однак я бачу приклади вживання:

  > В обох випадках — і в плані політичної роботи, і в методах звикло йшли напомацки, шарпаючись з одного кінця в другий, не ведучи маси за собою, але йдучи за нею. //Дмитро Донцов, «Підстави нашоі політики», 1921.
  >
  > В якому плані трактував Маркс той начебто й рідний йому рух? В плані сучасної йому боротьби, і саме тоді, коли воно, зігравши свою революційну роль, продовжувало культивувати гегелівський ідеалізм. Ми ж на молодогегельянство мусимо дивитись в плані ретроспекції і прикладати до нього об'єктивний метод. //Микола Хвильовий, «Україна чи Малоросія», 1926.
  >
  > Пишучи два роки тому про «Поетичну діяльність Куліша» і розглядаючи матеріали його «Позиченої кобзи», — правда, в плані історико-літературному, — я прийшов був до висновку, що на тлі своїх попередників і навіть багатьох сучасників Куліш-перекладач був великим кроком наперед, а деякі стилістичні особливості його перекладів не втратили свого значення навіть для нашої доби, як прекрасний приклад вирощування на ґрунті народно-поетичного та старо-книжницького стилю «художливо-кунштовного слова». //Микола Зеров, «У справі віршованого перекладу», 1928.

<sub>При підготовці відповіді використовувалися матеріали [Генерального регіонально анотованого корпусу української мови (ГРАК)](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/?corpname=grac3).</sub>